# Edit images inserted by CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I use CKEditor for ASP. NET with Enhanced Image in my site. When I insert Image I get code which Isn't good to me. I would like to replace some tags. I tried to replace tags using String.Replace, String.IndexOf etc. methods, but it does not make sens. I would like to try modify sourde code of CKEditor in order to achieve my goal. When I use simple picture, without signature/description, I get code like this (float depends of selected option):

```
<p>
<img width="481" height="361" style="float:right" src="/Images/ev1.jpg" alt="">
</p>
```

I'd like to convert it to this:

```
<a data-lightbox="gallery" href="/Images/ev1.jpg" class="image-container span4" style="float:right;margin:5px">
    <img class="shadow" style="margin:5px" src="/Images/ev1.jpg">
</a>
```

Another result is when I use image description. I get this code:

```
<figure class="image" style="float:left">
<img width="579" height="445" src="/Images/ev2.jpg" alt="">
<figcaption>This is picture description</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Which should look like this:

```
<a data-lightbox="postPhoto" href="/Images/ev2.jpg" class="image-container span4" style="float:left;margin:5px">
   <img width="579" height="445" src="/Images/ev2.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="overlay">This is picture description</div>
</a>
```

Could you, please, help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Too long to be a comment.

Is this with the image or the image2 plugin? This is a massive change - I'm sure you don't want to edit the CKE source to do this, but rather listen for image insertion and then edit the inserted element on the fly. As for the events you might want to listen to, have a look at [the awesome CKE docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) - there are 60 different events there, one of them might be suitable for you.

Alternatively you could make your own image plugin - it's actually quite doable, the plugin guides and system is very nice in CKEditor. Especially if the images can be widgets and do something like a copy of image2.

Also, converting a naturally block level element (`p` and `figure`) to an inline element (`a`) is a *big* semantic change - are you sure you want to do that? Surely you want some block level parent instead of putting them directly on the body like that? Try to evaluate your requirements as well as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've lately made similar adjustment to the image2 plugin, changes are to plugin.js in the image2 folder (ckeditor/plugins/image2/plugin.js), one of the first lines:

```
var template = '<a href="" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img alt="" src=""></a>',
```

and then just before this.parts.image.setAttributes I added

```
this.parts.link.setAttributes( {
                    href: this.data.src,
                    'data-lightbox': this.data.alt
                } );
```

This creates the image with lightbox clickon, however options for data-lightbox and data-title are not incorporated in the dialog yet, this is a further optimization, but this should get you started